# Hibernate JPA - Error: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm writing my first Hibernate JPA project. I have a very common issue (I found many articles about it) but no solution for me.

When i run application I've got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JpaTest2
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at net.andy.DatabaseAccess.testJpa(DatabaseAccess.java:55)
at net.andy.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>net.andy.Writer</class>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
     <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/> -->
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
     <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
  </properties>
```

And this is my class where I try to save something to db:

```
    public static void testJpa() {

    // Use persistence.xml configuration

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JpaTest2");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // Work with the EM
    Writer w = new Writer();
    //MapEntity map = new MapEntity();
    w.setId(5);

    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    em.persist(w);
    transaction.commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close(); 
}
```

I have read many articles which describes this error. 
So far I have:

1. added  line in persistence.xml.
2. changed persistence.xml
   location (I've tried probably everyone location also meta-inf
   folder, myproject/src etc.)
3. added libs hibernate-core,
   hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-commons-annotations,
   ejb3-persistence, hibernate-jpa, jta, postgresqljdbc (and a few
   more).

How to solve this? Almost code above is copied from tutorials, so I think there are some problems in libs or project structure, but can't find correct reason of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the persistence unit in your persistence.xml is `pu3`, while in your code when constructing the EntityManagerFactory you use `JpaTest2`. Try amending that first (use the same name).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that mistake. I've changed name, but have the same error.

Comment: ok it's a start; now you need to make sure that hibernate-entityframework is in your classpath. And did you strip out the root element from persistence.xml you posted in the question intentionally?

Comment: Thanks for help. I looked again through my classpath as you said. I've found out that I havent add one jar for jpa. I've downloaded hibernate archive before which have folder libs/required and there was no hibernate-entitymanager.jar. It was in different catalog and that's why I've forgot about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to configure `dependencies` in `pom.xml`. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html) : to setup the configuration.

pom.xml

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```